# Create radial Timer

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I Want to create an radial timer.
The Problem is, the arc are not painting correctly, when i try to set the start and end angle.

Thats, what i want:
[image]

Here is my code:

```js
var Timer = function Timer(selector) {
    var _width = 134;
    var _height = 134;
    var _x = _width / 2;
    var _y = _height / 2;
    var _canvas = null;
    var _context = null;
    var _percentage = 0;
    var _background = '#000000';
    var _foreground = '#FF0000';
    
    this.init = function init(selector) {
     var element = document.querySelector(selector);
     _canvas  = document.createElement('canvas');
     
     _canvas.setAttribute('width', _width);
     _canvas.setAttribute('height', _height);
     element.parentNode.replaceChild(_canvas, element);
     _context = _canvas.getContext('2d');
    
     this.paint();
    };
    
    this.clear = function clear() {
     _context.clearRect(0, 0, _width, _height);
    };
    
    this.start = function start(seconds) {
     var current  = seconds;
     var _watcher = setInterval(function AnimationInterval() {
      _percentage = 100 * current / seconds;
      
      if(_percentage < 0) {
       _percentage = 0;
       clearInterval(_watcher);
      } else if(_percentage > 100) {
       _percentage = 100;
       clearInterval(_watcher);
      }
      
      this.paint();
      
      console.log(_percentage + '%');
      --current;
     }.bind(this), 1000);
    };
    
    this.paint = function paint() {
     this.clear();
     this.paintBackground();
     this.paintForeground();
    };
    
    this.paintForeground = function paintForeground() {
     _context.beginPath();
     _context.arc(_x, _y, 134 / 2 - 5, -(Math.PI / 2), ((Math.PI * 2) * _percentage) - (Math.PI / 2), false);
     _context.lineWidth  = 8;
     _context.strokeStyle = _foreground;
     _context.stroke();    
    };
    
    this.paintBackground = function paintBackground() {
     _context.beginPath();
     _context.arc(_x, _y, 134 / 2 - 5, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
     _context.lineWidth  = 10;
     _context.strokeStyle = _background;
     _context.stroke();
    };
    
    this.init(selector);
   };

   var timer = new Timer('timer');
   timer.start(10);
```

```html
<timer></timer>
```

Can you tell me, what i make wrong?

Comment: I recommend bringing it down to a minimal case, and then expanding to whatever you may need

Comment: You need to divide percentage by 100 when drawing the arc in `paintForeground`: `((Math.PI * 2) * _percentage/100`

Comment: @towc when you see/execute the script, you see an minimal case. The Image/Picture is an example, what i need.

Comment: @Giladd OMG, what a mistake. Big thanks!

Comment: @AdrianPreuss no, you don't know what a minimal case is